# Concave function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove that three statements are equal.

1. $f(x)$ is a concave function.
2. $f(x) \leq f(x^\star)+\nabla f(x^\star)(x-x^\star)$ for all $x, x^\star$
3. For all $x$ the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is negative semi-definite.

Comment: Can you reformulate your question using Mathjax (just like Latex coding) format? Also, item 2 is incomplete, I think you meant: $$x>x^{*} \implies f(x) \geq f(x^{*}).$$

Comment: Note that the statements are only equivalent in the case that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hatebrij commented, the statements are equivalent only assuming that $f\in C^2$, in which case:

### 3. $\Rightarrow$ 2.

Given distinct $x,x^\star$, by exact second order Taylor expansion you have that there exists $t\in(0,1)$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x^\star)
={}&
f(x)
+
\langle\nabla f(x),x^\star-x\rangle
+
\frac12
\Bigl\langle
  x^\star-x,~
  \nabla^2 f\bigl(tx^\star+(1-t)x\bigr)(x^\star-x)
\Bigr\rangle
\\
\leq{}&
f(x)
+
\langle\nabla f(x),x^\star-x\rangle
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from negative semi-definiteness of the Hessian.

### 2. $\Rightarrow$ 1.

We want to prove that for any $t\in(0,1)$ and for any distinct points $x,x^\star$ it holds that $f(tx + (1-t)x^\star) > tf(x) + (1-t)f(x^\star)$.
\begin{align}
(1-t)f(x^\star) + tf(x)
\leq{} &
(1-t)\Bigl[
f(x) + \langle\nabla f(x),x^\star-x\rangle
\Bigr]
+
t\Bigl[
f(x^\star) + \langle\nabla f(x),x-x^\star\rangle
\Bigr]
\\
={} &
tf(x) + (1-t)f(x^\star)
\end{align}
as expected.
Above, we used the concave inequalities
\begin{align}
f(x) \leq{} & f(x^\star) + \langle\nabla f(x^\star),x-x^\star\rangle
\\
f(x^\star) \geq{} & f(x) + \langle\nabla f(x^\star),x-x^\star\rangle
\end{align}

### 1. $\Rightarrow$ 3.

You can consider $\varphi(t) = f(tx + (1-t)x^\star)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, noticing that
\begin{align}
\varphi'(t)
={}&
\langle\nabla f(tx + (1-t)x^\star),~x-x^\star\rangle
\\
\varphi''(t)
={}&
\langle x-x^\star,~ \nabla^2 f(tx + (1-t)x^\star)(x-x^\star)\rangle
\end{align}
to reduce the problem to the one-dimensional case.
I'll leave it to you to show that $\varphi\in C^2$ is concave iff $\varphi''\leq 0$.

Comment: is it possible if we prove this without using Taylor expansion?